# How do I manage files (upload/delete) in an asp.net core web application using a razor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I am trying to make a **razor page** where I can upload/delete files out of a specific folder in wwwroot I have found many ways to do it but I want to use a **razor component** so I can reuse it on **multiple pages** I found in the documentation to upload a files
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore5.0&pivots=webassembly)

and many videos an element called
`<InputFile />`
but when I try to use it says that it isn't a valid element?

Comment: There are already components that allow upload: e.g. https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload

Comment: Do you mean something like view component? Blazor does not support it but you can build [reusable UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components).You can also share your code for us to locate the problem

Comment: @JerryCai I am trying to use Blazor to make reusable UI and I'll try user3442535's solution and if it doesn't work I'll send my code